# Unhandled Rejection (InvalidTokenError) Using async and await

Tags: javascript, error-handling, async-await, unhandled-exception

Although using `await` in the right place and catching any possible errors, when the token is undefined the following function throws the error "Unhandled Rejection (InvalidTokenError): Invalid token specified: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined":

```
async function authenticateUsingExistingToken() {
  const userToken = localStorage.FBIdToken;
  if (userToken) {
    const decodedToken = jwtDecode(userToken);
    if (decodedToken.exp * 1000 < Date.now()) {
      resetUserContext();
      localStorage.FBIdToken = "";
    } else {
      axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = userToken;
      try {
        const responseObj = await axios.get("/user");
        setUserStates(responseObj.data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error("Authentication Error! err: ", err);
      }
    }
  } else {
    resetUserContext();
  }
}
authenticateUsingExistingToken();
```

The `setUserStates` and `resetUserContext` only do some setStates using React Hooks. The only Promise for data fetching is where I've used `await`.

I'd appreciate it if you give me some ideas on why such an error is thrown. The console reports the error happened in the last line of the function where `}` is closing it!

Here is the complete error stack:

```
./node_modules/jwt-decode/lib/index.js
C:/MY_FOLDER/client/node_modules/jwt-decode/lib/index.js:9
__webpack_require__
C:/MY_FOLDER/client/webpack/bootstrap:785
fn
C:/MY_FOLDER/client/webpack/bootstrap:150
Module../src/components/Auth/SignInUp/SignInUp.js
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:374:68
__webpack_require__
C:/MY_FOLDER/client/webpack/bootstrap:785
fn
C:/MY_FOLDER/client/webpack/bootstrap:150
Module../src/containers/App/App.js
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:2599:92
__webpack_require__
C:/MY_FOLDER/client/webpack/bootstrap:785
fn
C:/MY_FOLDER/client/webpack/bootstrap:150
Module../src/index.js
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:3173:77
__webpack_require__
C:/MY_FOLDER/client/webpack/bootstrap:785
fn
C:/MY_FOLDER/client/webpack/bootstrap:150
1
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:3328:18
__webpack_require__
C:/MY_FOLDER/client/webpack/bootstrap:785
checkDeferredModules
C:/MY_FOLDER/client/webpack/bootstrap:45
Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push]
C:/MY_FOLDER/client/webpack/bootstrap:32
(anonymous function)
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1:67
```

Comment: so somewhere in your codebase, either clientside or on the server, there's a `.replace` function running. Can you try to find it?

Comment: @TKoL, it's funny that I've not used `.replace` anywhere in the client or server-side code. I think that is defined inside the `useState` hook in  React.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the value of userToken being undefined and on your error location (though it should be based on error stack) the exception could have been raised from `resetUserContext()`.

If possible can you share that function? after maybe hiding any sensitive data.

Comment: this should be a comment.

Comment: @Mayank, thank you for your response. I updated the question and added the information you asked.

Comment: @TKoL sorry, I have recently joined SOF and atm I cannot comment anywhere expect on my own posts. I will keep your suggestion in mind for future references

Answer (score 0):

Found it! The error was generated from `jwtDecode`. Because the function is defined as `async`, and throwing the error in `jwtDecode` does not resolve or reject the promise, the error was generated. To solve this issue, I surrounded `jwtDecode` in a `try` and caught the error. Thanks for your responses, anyway.